# Extract html from url with DOM

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I've already search about this but most of the topics used java language, but i need using DOM in PHP. I wanna extract this element from example.com :

```
<div id="download" class="large-12  medium-12  columns hide-for-small-only">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" link="https://mediamusic.com/media/mp3/mp3-256/Mas.mp3" target="_blank" class="mp3_download_link">
  <i class="fa fa-cloud-download">Download Now</i>
  </a>
</div>
```

How can i get `mp3_download_link` class from this code using DOM in PHP! as i said i have already search about this but really i confused...

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @u_mulder Yes, `getElementsByTagName` but i need to extract that class out of html code

Answer (score 1):

You can use library to parsing DOM. For example: https://github.com/tburry/pquery

Usage:

```
$dom = pQuery::parseStr($html);
$class = $dom->query('#download a')->attr('class');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try **file_get_html** to parse html

```
$html=file_get_html('http://demo.com');
```

and use the below to get all the attributes of anchor tag.

```
foreach($html->find('div[id=download] a') as $a){
  var_dump($a->attr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have this DOM as a string. Then you may use built-in DOM extension to get link you need. Here is the example of a code:

```
$domstring = '<div id="download" class="large-12  medium-12  columns hide-for-small-only">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" link="https://mediamusic.com/media/mp3/mp3-256/Mas.mp3" target="_blank" class="mp3_download_link">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-download">Download Now</i>
  </a>
</div>';
$links = array();
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->loadHTML($domstring);//here $domstring is a string containing html you posted in your question
$node_list = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($node_list as $node) {
  $links[] = $node->getAttribute('link');
}

print_r(array_shift($links));
```

Comment: just use array_shift() on it

Comment: so if you need a class value for the link use getAttribute('class') in foreach loop

Comment: thanx bro but unfortunately it doesnt worked yet! white screen

Comment: Have you sent proper $domstring to it on line 3? check my example again. I've posted fully working code in it.

Comment: @alex_edav Yes thanx! but i set $domstring value into url. how about this? can i set url and then it just automatically print that url ?

Comment: You may use `$domstring = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');` to download remote html file and use the code posted above. But if you download a whole html page it will have more complex structure than in your example. So you will need to add additional logic to get <a> tag you need. These two articles from php.net will help you to go further [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file%20get%20contents), [DOM](http://php.net/dom).